# How to Stick configuration file to a particular Azure Slot

Tags: azure, sitecore

Our project is in sitecore and using Azure - App service for deployment. We have created staging slot and apart from application setting and connection string want to make some configuration file slot specific(stick to slot while swapping).

Is there a way to make whole configuration file to stick to a particular slot?

We also tried to write some sitecore configuration in app setting option in azure and ticked it to make it stick to slot but still it is getting swapped.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make whole configuration file to stick to a particular slot?

No, it is not possible (as of date of writing this answer, as azure is evolving all the time).

[Here](http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/) you can see details of slot swap procedure. My rewriting:

1. Production slot settings applied to staging slot -> site restart
2. Staging slot warmup
3. Host names for production & staging slots get swapped.
4. Staging slot settings applied to (new) staging slot -> (new) staging slot restart

So basically slot setting is really specific feature; other than that slots are just separate sites, with different host names, ftp shares etc.

Any logic like "I want to have file sticked to slot" should be implemented in some custom way.

For example you can consider using config transforms (you can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236541/can-i-use-web-config-transform-when-publishing-to-azure-with-visual-studio-2012) as a start).

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure portal you can add AppSettings and mark them as "Slot Specific". These can be read from the application using normal System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings semantics.

There's no way to ask Azure programmatically which slot the app is running in to my knowledge.

Comment: For web.config I am able to do the same thing as you have specified..but for otjer configuraion in sitecore config files if I specify it in Application setting in azure portal it is not working..let suppose if have configuration is sitecore config file new=hello and in Application setting I specify new=hi then it is taking hello(from config file rather than app setting)

Comment: How about you have a set of Sitecore settings with names like "MyKey.Slot" and then create regular app settings, per slot as above, that point you to the setting you need to read. 2 levels of misdirection, as it were.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? I am currently specifying the sitecore setting in App setting mentioned on azure portal but it is not taking that setting. I am deploying code from tfs to azure app service staging environment.  And I have specified in sitecore setting in the App setting section but still it is not taking that setting . For other configuration like : app setting config it is working fine

Comment: Let's say you are trying to specify 2 target email addresses, one in the _backstage_ slot and one in the _production_ slot.  Create 2 Sitecore settings called `<setting name="TargetEmail.Production" />` and `<setting name="TargetEmail.Backstage" />`.  In your Azure slot-specific settings (in the portal) create a setting called `TargetEmailSetting` and set the value to `TargetEmail.Backstage` or `TargetEmail.Production` as appropriate.  In code... `Sitecore.GetSetting( AppSettings["TargetEmailSetting"] )` - untested, but something like that

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add AppSettings into the Azure Portal's Application Settings and have those setting stick to the slot.  These settings will override whatever is in the web.config.  For example, if you have an Azure Portal AppSetting of key "Greeting" and value of "Welcome", and the web.config has the same AppSetting with value of "Hello" - the result will be "Welcome".  If there is an AppSetting in the web.config that is not in the Azure settings, then it will use the web.config value.

[image]

Comment: For web.config I am able to do the same thing as you have specified..but for otjer configuraion in sitecore config files if I specify it in Application setting in azure portal it is not working..let suppose if have configuration is sitecore config file new=hello and in Application setting I specify new=hi then it is taking hello(from config file rather than app setting)